# How to Python unquote Chinese URLs?

Tags: python, urlencode

```
url = /%E7%89%B9%E6%9C%97%E6%99%AE%E6%84%9F%E6%9F%93%E6%96%B0%E5%86%A0%E4%B9%8B%E5%90%8E%EF%BC%9A%E6%9C%89%E5%85%B3%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD%E5%A4%A7%E9%80%89%E5%91%BD%E8%BF%90%E7%AD%89%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%E7%9A%84

urllib.parse.unquote(url)
```

Gives me:

```
'/特朗普感染新冠之后：有关美国大选命运等问题的'
```

Instead of that "：", i want to get:

```
拜登和佩洛西批评特朗普淡化新冠疫情严重性的声
```

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: Why do you assume `:` is in error? Your desired output is very different from the encoded one too. Are you sure they match?

Comment: I'll double-check!

Comment: try to decode your url at [here](https://www.urldecoder.org/). it is correct value which you got.